# How apply parsed XML information to UIView ? Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am creating a app where in i have to request the server which gives the response in a XML format, like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
- <playlist>
  <id>CTx8wE0GMzGvZYeg</id>
  <title>playlist_ios</title>
  <layout_size>640,480</layout_size>
  <split_events />
- <content>
  <time_offset>0</time_offset>
  <type>image</type>
  <file>file_CT9QhPWBFpZ2ym7c.png</file>
  <position>0,0,640,480</position>
  <duration>59</duration>
  </content>
  </playlist>
```

so this XML file has the title, layoutsize, image(which i have downloaded locally), position and duration. I am parsing these values which are in a string format.. i need to load these to a viewcontroller.. how do i do it?

Comment: Step 1) Parse the XML to get the info you need
Step 2) Create a UIView and apply that information to it

If you are having trouble, edit your question to be more specific about either step 1 or step 2

Comment: @borrrden actually having trouble in step 2.. how to apply that information. stuck helPP! Thanks :)

Comment: So how have you parsed the XML?  What format are you storing it in memory?  NSDictionary?  NSArray?  Not storing it at all, just reading it?

Comment: @borrrden  just reading it right now, but have to store.

Comment: What do you want the XML values to cause to happen in the view controller?

Comment: @PhillipMills an example: seeing the XML file dat i am using right now has some image and position associated with it.. when i fetch information from XML i want the image to be displayed according to the positions specified in the XMl file.. Thanks for ur interest :)

Comment: Roughly....  Create a `UIImage` object from the image file, create a `UIImageView` with the `UIImage`, add it as a subview of your view controller's main view, make a `CGRect` from the position information and set that as the `UIImageView`'s frame.

Comment: @PhillipMills i want it to take the positions from XML file itself i don wanna Hardcode it anyway.

Comment: @PhillipMills Its like, Link the XML parsed string values to my code which will be generic to any XMl file..after u do dat the view shuld take the layout according to XML values :) Hope its clear, Thanks

Comment: That's what I said: "make a CGRect from the position information".  (That is, when you parse the 4 values in the position tag, use them as x, y, width, height.)

Comment: @PhillipMills I gocha! any sample code ??.. thanks man!